# Add GData to Zend Framework2

Tags: zend-framework2, gdata, zend-gdata

Okay, so this has proven to be more difficult than I expected and think it should be.

All I want to do is utilize the GData library for some youtube functionality in my site. However, I can't seem to figure out how to add everything in so Zend recognizes the classes.

I've downloaded the latest ZendGdata archive, and added the contents of \library into \vendor\Zend. Next step is to autoload all that into my application right? I've tried searching for how to do it, but nothing has helped. Now I look to you, stackoverflow. Please help me figure this madness out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about ditching manually installing vendors and using [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) which will manage all the autoloading stuff for you?

Download composer.phar into your project's root directory and run `init` to create a basic configuration:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar init
```

Follow the prompts, when it comes to searching for required packages, select `zendframework/zendgdata` and use the version `dev-master`. (If you decided to use composer for all your dependencies which I recommend, you could also at this point add `zendframework/zendframework: 2.*`).

Once you've done that a `composer.json` file will have been created. Next install your dependencies:

```
php composer.phar install
```

Once that's all done, there should be a `vendor/autoload.php` file that you require from your entrypoint to have autoloading of your composer dependencies working.